# Web Scraper via Web Service API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, screen-scraping

How would I go about doing the following...

I want to build a web service for my application to grab a piece of data from an external website, that requires the user to login. The website has no public API , hence the reason for the scraper.

Is there a library to perform the following functions? or what do I do?

- automate fill-in form, auto click
- Automate submit button
- check which URL the user has landed
  on, and redirect user to URL
- Grab data from label.

EDIT: what im asking for is there a web service, library etc to make it easier to perform screen scraping/automation functions???

Comment: If site does not provide an API - then they don't want their content to be stolen. Guys, aren't there a **legal** developers positions that doesn't involved in any kind of theft?

Comment: mint.com - the bank doesn't have an API, mint.com uses automated backend software to login to the bank to pull the user's account statement from the user's bank website. (example)

Comment: So let me get this straight - your screen scraping a banking website?? Say hello to the feds for me.

Comment: Actually banking websites like Mint.com, yodlee, wesabe, etc all store your username/password.  It's not illegal if the user consents to it and they are PCI compliant.

Comment: There is nothing illegal about scraping a banking website as long as you are PCI compliant (if required) and you have the user's consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filling a form and virtually clicking buttons, you should look at the source of the form, and figure out how the data is being submitted. In most cases you can simply send a post request with the log in data. If there is something special besides a simple post request, I use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) to figure out what requests are being done that you can't see. Using C#, I would use the HttpWebRequest class because it handles cookies for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the website does not ban robots, you can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to simulate everything you need. However, it can be a bit difficult or impossible as you basically have to implement a text-only browser within JS.